# `fillColor` is not working in google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am trying to apply `fillColor` for polylines like this.[image]

But I couldn't do that.Whats wrong here?

```
poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
          strokeColor: '#00DB00',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          fillColor: 'green',
          fillOpacity: 0.05
        });
        poly.setMap(map);
```

fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/vL6qpn4w/

`Doubt`: how to draw polygon using my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polylines do not support fill colors as they are simple lines. Try using a polygon instead, that has fill and stroke attributes - giving what you are trying for above.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygons

```
poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
      strokeColor: '#00DB00',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: 'green',
      fillOpacity: 0.05 //Increase this to make the green background darker
    });
    poly.setMap(map);
```

New Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c3znthny/1/

Comment: I got polygon https://jsfiddle.net/vL6qpn4w/2/.But I want to create it when user clicks on google map not with predefined values.How to do it?